# How to delete a subnode from xml that is not present in a list

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml.etree

I have a xml with different number of node levels. I want to check every node from the Tree and remove it only when it and its children are not present in the list

```
<node1>
  <xxx>
     stuff
  </xxx>
  <subnode2>
     <yyy>
        stuf2
     </yyy>
  </subnode2>
</node1>
```

My problem is that if 'yyy' is in the dontRemove list and its parent is not so yyy still will be cleared.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

document = ET.parse("foo.xml")
root = document.getroot()

#list of nodes
toRemove = root.findall('.//')

#list of tags that shouldn't be removed
dontRemove = ['xxx','yyy']

#take element from root and compare it with "dont remove it", if it's present remove from removing list
for element in list(toRemove):
    string = str(element)
    string = string.split(" ")
    string = string[1].replace("'", '')
    print(string)
    removed = 0
    for i in range(len(dontRemove)):
        if dontRemove[i] in string and removed == 0:
            toRemove.remove(element)
            removed = 1
#removing: 
for i in range(len(toRemove)):
    toRemove[i].clear()
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what is the rule - if a tag is not to be removed, but the tag and all its ancestors  (all the way to the root) should also not be removed?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want to check every tag from Tree and remove it only when it and its childs are not present in the list

Comment: So when a node has two children, one in the "don't remove" list and one which is not there, what gets removed and what stays?

Comment: So parent and child that is present in dont remove shouldnt be removed. The 2nd child should be removed (if it's children are not present in the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if element should be removed recurrently - if it contains at least one "nonremovable" child, it should not.

```
dontRemove = ['xxx','yyy']
elements_to_remove = []

def should_not_be_removed(parent):
    if parent.tag in dontRemove:
        return True

    nonremovable_child_found = False
    for child in parent:
        if should_not_be_removed(child):
            nonremovable_child_found = True
    if not nonremovable_child_found:
        elements_to_remove.append(parent)
    return nonremovable_child_found

should_not_be_removed(root)
```

After this recurrent calls starting with root `elements_to_remove` contains a list of elements which do not contain child with tag specified in `dont remove`

I also extended your xml to cover more test cases, check if that's what you meant:

```
<node1>
    <xxx>
        don't remove
    </xxx>
    <subnode2>
        <yyy>
            don't remove
        </yyy>
    </subnode2>
    <subnode3>
        remove
    </subnode3>
    <subnode4>
        <xxx>
            don't remove
        </xxx>
        <abc>
            remove
        </abc>
    </subnode4>
</node1>
```